# Get a integer from a string in c

Tags: c, string, char, integer

```
    char str[]="abcde1fgh";
    int i;
    i=str[5];
    return;
```

After this process, the integer i must be 1. But it doesn't. Why not?

Comment: It's not `1`, it's `'1'`.

Comment: Character '1' is not the same thing as number 1.

Comment: I googled it for an hour and couldn't find an answer that I can understand. Then I found tihs site and thought you guys can help

Comment: to get the integer 1 as you want, you just do "i=str[5] - '0'", here the character '0' is the offset you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code does not work because in your example `1` is a char. 
Try the following instead:

```
int i = str[5] - '0';
```

Here is why it works: *Based on Jamal's explanation from his comment below*

The numerical value is obtained by subtracting some character e.g. `str[5]` with the character `'0'`. The numeric value for each character is found in the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) table. In this example, we are subtracting `49` (corresponding to `'1'`) minus `48` (corresponding to `'0'`) which equals `1`.

Comment: Why post the same answer twice? You can edit your first answer.

Comment: @user3080477: You can get a numerical value by subtracting the character (from your `char[]`) and the character `0`.  This can be found on an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).  Here, that would be 49 (corresponding to `1`) minus 48 (corresponding to `0`), which is 1.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks Jamal